# Concatenate rows per group in RDLC report

Tags: visual-studio, concatenation, reportviewer, rdlc

Is it possible to concatenate rows into single one? Attached image shows what is required. First table is what I get and second table is what I need. It is the same as SUM function but  just need to concatenate strings instead of sum calculation.

I am unable to change datasource.

[image: example]

Answer (score -2):

You can use the & operator.

```
=Exp1 & ", " & Exp2 & ", " & Exp3
```

This concatenates the three values with dots between them.

Comment: I think the three (or more) expression are on different rows of the DataSource.